# ActiveRecord quote raw value without checking out connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is it possible to quote raw fields before inserting without checking out an `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` via `connection.quote`?

I basically want to build an array of insert strings and do a mass insert, but only checkout a connection when I'm ready to insert.

Right now it looks like I have to do this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |conn|
  values = 10_000.times.map { |i| "(#{conn.quote(i)})" }  # psuedo example
  mass_insert(conn, values)
end
```

But what I really want is something like:

```
values = 10_000.times.map { |i| "(#{ActiveRecord.some_quote_method(i)})" }  
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |conn|
  mass_insert(conn, values)
end
```

Is that possible. Can't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: Isn't the whole point that `conn.quote` gets the database to properly escape the values?

Comment: Looks like it's internal: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ee291b9b41a959e557b7732100d1ec3f27aae4f8/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb#L8

Comment: Ah, right. Can't you just include `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Quoting`  and call `10_000.times.map { |i| "(#{quote(i)})" }`?